# Create a textbox in html, customize-able, and the string inserted gets stored in a var

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

How can I create, in HTML, a textbox which I can customize with CSS and has a character limit, and the string that the user passes gets stored in a js var?
I want the data to be submitted when, let's say, the function `submit()` gets executed.

I've try researching but I don't see any tutorial with what I want. I've seen tutorials of how to make forms but I want just the one textbox.

I'm sorry I don't include any code, but I still don't have nothing regarding this part of my project.

Thank you.

**EDIT:** Also, is there a way to know, as the user types, how many character he or she has left?

Comment: Is the textbox part of a form? Do you want to access the value when the user presses submit? Or do you want to access the value at the same time the user is typing? You need to be clearer about your intents.

Comment: the INPUT tag creates a text box, a form can be a single text box, you can use an event to get the value into a variable, first create the text box with input, then post if you need help with the event side. Even easier is a form with a single textbox and a onclick() attached to the buttom, which runs the function to get the value into the variable.

Comment: @MiguelM. Edited! I had already explained that I just wanted one text box though.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understood your question, you basically want an HTML textbox, with a limited numer of characters to insert, and then access the value of the textbox with a JS var... If it's that, than you can put a `textarea` with an HTML attribute, `maxlength="...your number..."` . You will need to put then an `id` both for CSS styling and js var. In your js part then you will just have to put:

```
var textbox = document.getElementById("your textarea/input id").value;
```

That has to be all you need, if the question was that

Comment: Thanks! By the way, is there a way to know, as the user types, how many character he or she has left?